# Email sent! But not received on inbox. PHP -> localhost -> XAMPP -> Web Server

Tags: php, email, outlook, xampp, localhost

Here are my configuration files.

sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=(Correct SMTP Server)

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25
```

php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = (Correct SMTP Server)
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = (user@(server.com)) <- correct name
```

PHP code

```
<?php
$from_name = "testing";
$from_email = "myemail@something.com";
$headers = "From: $from_name <$from_email>";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$body = "Hi,\nThis is a test mail from $from_name <$from_email>.";
$subject = "Test mail from test";
$to = "myemail@something.com";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  echo "success!";
} else {
  echo "fail…";
}
?>
```

When i ran the code, it indeed say email sent but when I checked the email, there is nothing to receive... please help! thank you i will provide as many relevant information as possible to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sending it to a large domain (e.g. gmail, aol, yahoo)?  If so sending mail without taking certain steps (proper DNS, non-generic hostname for your IP) will increase your spam score.  Also, are you authenticating with the SMTP server if it requires it?

Comment: Do you have an MX record set up?

Comment: @drew I am sending it to the company's microsoft outlook email. I did not authenticate with the SMTP server because it does not require any authentication user and password.

Comment: @blake Pardon my lack of knowledge sir, but what is MX record set up?

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing this from home or a small office then your ISP is likely to be blocking out-bound traffic on port 25. You're PHP will not fail but your message will be blocked. You'll need to connect to an external SMTP server on another port such as 465 or 587. Consult your ISP's website for the details on what they allow.

Comment: Resist, i tried both 465 and 587 port number. It does not work, and no i am not testing from home or a small office. I am currently working in a MNC.. Is there any other way I can approach this? Thank you

Comment: Okay latest update: I used my own personal hotmail address to send to the company's email and it worked. Vice versa, i used my company's email to send "test" to my personal hotmail address. This shows that the company does not block out-bound traffic, what could be the problem now? Anyone? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely you will see you're missing a concatenation on your second $header variable, therefor, you're not sending the "From:" header which is likely causing the mail to be rejected.