# Cannot receive email from localhost wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, xampp, localhost

|My situation is similar to this link: [Email sent! But not received on inbox. PHP -> localhost -> XAMPP -> Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117170/email-sent-but-not-received-on-inbox-php-localhost-xampp-web-server)

Environment:

```
Windows 7
XAMPP 1.7.7
Apache/2.2.21
PHP/5.3.8
Wordpress 3.5.1
Woocommerce 2.0.8
```

sendmail.ini (These are the only 4 settings uncommented

```
smtp_server=192.168.10.38
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
```

php.ini

```
SMTP = 192.168.10.38
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
```

This is the most interesting part: Actually the email is sent successfully.  Here is the /var/log/maillog:

```
Apr 29 17:36:57 LNXWEBSR01DEV sendmail[20224]: r3T9aueJ020224: from=<xxx@yyy.com>, size=6751, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<50c1838f127b57eff8f50661739a1dec@localhost>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=[192.168.11.79]

Apr 29 17:36:57 LNXWEBSR01DEV sendmail[20226]: STARTTLS=client, relay=zzzzzz.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256

Apr 29 17:36:57 LNXWEBSR01DEV sendmail[20226]: r3T9aueJ020224: to=<xxx@yyy.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=36751, relay=zzzzzz.com. [111.222.333.444], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (ok:  Message 6887705 accepted)
```

However, I did not receive any email using MS outlook 2010.  I installed Symantec Endpoint protection and when I test it, I disable that already.

I have tried setting up own email server using Mercury.  When I tried sending email using Mercury Admin UI, I can receive the email from Outlook!!  However, when I do the same on wordpress, it does not work.

I have tried using WP mail SMTP plugin to enable SMTP, the test email is received successfully using Outlook, but when I use wordpress to send the order email again, no email received.

Someone may suggest me to use Gmail, however my company is blocking Gmail SMTP and therefore I am only forced to use internal SMTP only.

Since this is an internal SMTP, no authentication is required.

Can anyone please give me some advice on this?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a configuration problem between your apache smtp server and xampp.

Try uninstalling Mercury and Xampp, then install the [full pack of Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641) (not Portable one), Mercury is included!

Finally when you open Xampp Control start Apache, MySQL and Mercury. 
You should be capable of send mails without doing anything more.

Comment: Thanks.  I am now using another way to do the same thing.  Thank you for your support anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what might be causing the issue, you can use the plugin [Check & Log Email](https://wordpress.org/plugins/check-email/). I highly recommend this plugin! It helped me find out the cause of my problem in minutes.

If the problem is that WordPress is trying to send emails from "WordPress@localhost" (I suspect it is), then you can just change the 'from address' and you'll be on your way.

WordPress has a filter for changing the 'from address' used by wp_mail. So you can easily do something like so:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'get_admin_email');

if(!function_exists('get_admin_email')) {
    function get_admin_email($email) {
        $wp_from = get_option('admin_email');
        return $wp_from;
    }
}
```

The code above tells WordPress to use the admin email address as the 'from address'.

Further reading:

[WordPress Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_from/)

[My Blog](https://mwale.me/error-email-could-not-be-sent-site-may-not-be-correctly-configured-wordpress-not-sending-emails-on-localhost-xampp/)

HTH, Mwale